# Google Sheet - Find partial match between ranges / columns

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

On Google Sheet, given two ranges / columns of data, lookup column A based on its partial match on column B, show empty if no matches.
Particularly in my case, given a list of blocks and a list of rooms with block prefix, identify the block for each room.

```
+--------+---------+------------------------+
| Block  |  Room   | Block of Room (Output) |
+--------+---------+------------------------+
| AD     | AD201   | AD                     |
| AE     | AD208/3 | AD                     |
| HG     | ADG07   | AD                     |
| HH     | ADUG8   | AD                     |
| HSH    | BY03    |                        |
|        | HG03    | HG                     |
|        | HGG01   | HG                     |
|        | HSH01   | HSH                    |
|        | HSHG5   | HSH                    |
+--------+---------+------------------------+
```

I tinkered with `search()`, `index()` and `match()` like this:
`=IFERROR(if(search(index($A$2:$A,MATCH(B2,$A$2:$A,1),1), B2), index($A$2:$A,MATCH(B2,$A$2:$A,1),1), ""))`
but it didn't work well with `arrayformula()`.

Finally I come up with a solution like this
`=ARRAYFORMULA( iferror(IF(SEARCH( VLOOKUP(B2:B,A2:A,1), B2:B), VLOOKUP(B2:B,A2:A,1), "")))`

I wonder if there exists more elegant ways to do the matching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(B2:B,"^("&TEXTJOIN("|",1,A2:A)&")")))
```

- JOIN blocks by `|`(= or in regex)
- Use that regex to extract block from room
- "^" represents start of string

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(LEFT(B2:B10,2)&"*",A2:A10,1,0))
```

Uses two characters from LEFT of Col B to lookup in A and return result. This should be faster than regex, but maybe a little less accurate.

Comment: Brilliant! I just couldn't work out how to do it. But may I suggest a small modification =ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(B2:B,TEXTJOIN("|",1,"^"&A2:A))) because  it has to match starting at the first character (e.g. HXHG shouldn't match HG)?

Comment: @Tom Thanks. Added. Along with another formula

Answer (score 0):

You could use Google Sheets add-ons like one I created called [Flookup](https://www.getflookup.com/). It should do exactly what you want.

For this case, we are going to use a function called [FLOOKUP](https://www.getflookup.com/documentation/spreadsheet-functions#h.dho9lnim1i2l). This is its syntax and what each parameter represents:

```
FLOOKUP (lookup_value, table_array, lookup_col, index_num, threshold, [rank])
```

- **lookup_value:** the value you're looking up
- **table_array:** the table you want to search
- **lookup_col:** the column you want to search
- **index_num:** the column you want data to be returned from
- **threshold:** the percentage similarity below which data shouldn't be returned
- **rank:** the nth best match (i.e. if the first one isn't to your
  liking)

I have decided to use a `threshold` value of 0.55 because, by scanning your dataset, I observed that the items in column A are about half the length of those in column B in general. This is a very non-scientific way of estimation, but it makes for a good starting point:

```
=FLOOKUP($A$1:$A$5, $B$1:$B$9, 1, 1, 0.55)
```

This formula picks every item in column A and searches for matches in column B. Matches are considered to be any text entries in column A that have a 0.55 level of similarity or higher to the items in column B.